# Show that There exists a canonical injective homomorphism between $G$ and $G\times H$

Tags: group-theory

Let $(G; *)$ and $(H; \cdot)$ be two groups.

The product $G\times H$ is defined by: $G\times H:= \{(g;h)\mid \forall g \in G\text{ and }\forall h \in H\}$

Show that that there exist a canonical injective homomorphism between $G$ and $G\times H$.

I have no idea how to go about with this problem

Comment: What about $g\mapsto (g;1)$?

Comment: Note that "canonical" more or less means that the solution is nearly impossible not to find. - So you are given an element $x\in G$ and nothing special from $H$. Which element $(g;h)$ of $G\times H$ could you write down with those givens and without knowing anything more detailed about $G$ and $H$? Well, $g$ must be an element of $G$ and we are given an element $x$ of $G$, so ... And $h$ must be an elemtn of $H$ and the only element of $H$ that wwe know to exist is ...

Comment: Would that be $e_H$ (the neutral element of H?